# Home eye sight test for myopia patients?

Tags: eye, eye-strain, myopia-nearsightedness

I am a 16 year old and have been diagnosed with myopia since I was 8. I apologise for using wrong terms in advance, since I am not too familiar with medical terms. I wish to become a software engineer, which requires me to prevent increase in my eye power. My eye power, when last tested was around 4, which is about an year and a half ago. I haven't stepped out since the Covid situation hit my country (India), and thus haven't been able to get my eye tested. However, I have had to use an enormous amount of screens due to online classes, etc. and I haven't been able to look at far objects since a long time.

I wanted to know a test I can take at home, just to give me an assurance that my eyes have not degraded to an extent which could be really harmful, in which case I would need to limit my screen time as much as possible. I plan on getting a LASIK done after I reach the required age but I need to keep my eye power under control for it. Also, professional opinions on whether LASIK is a safe option, and whether I should get it done would be highly appreciated and I would be grateful to you forever.

Thanks in advance,
Ravi Arora

Comment: Consult an eye doctor, but I don't believe that looking at monitors worsens myopia.

Comment: I see the "related links" list has some questions and answers on that very topic, well done related links algorithm.  But why isn't "are there reliable eye tests that can be done at home" an on-topic question?